# How to use a variable in google maps api

Tags: php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google maps api, from which I can convert the area name from latitude and longitude. Code given bellow :

```
<?php
$url="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=23.756879299999998,90.3801968&key=key";
```

Now I want to make this $url dynamically. Here I have `latlng= 23.756879299999998,90.3801968` I want to make it like this  `latlng = $lat,$long`

How I can make this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a simple string concat eg:

```
<?php
$lat= "23.756879299999998";
$lng = "90.3801968";

$url="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=".$lat.",".$lng."&key=key";
```